# Django - Static files don't serve in production

Tags: python, django, nginx

My site works well in local but when I put it on my server, it can't load the static files. Here's my files.

settings.py

```
DEBUG=False
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

All my static are in `/myproject/mymainapp/static`

I've got another directory "static" of the root of my project by doing manage collectstatic in production.

Here's my nginx conf file :

```
[...]
root /home/user/site/mymainapp/;
[...]
location /static {
    alias /home/user/site/mymainapp/static;
}
```

I've tried to set the path to my static directory in my root directory project but it don't make anything better.

My URLs patterns :

```
urlpatterns = [
    [...] nothing relative to static files
]
```

Maybe I should add something in my URLs patterns ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Where are you actual static files in the project structure? Have you run `collectstatic` in production?

Comment: Yes I've done it : 0 static files copied to '/home/user/myproject/static', 1319 unmodified.

I've got two statit directories, one in my root project and one in my main app directory (same files inside).

Comment: Is it '/home/user/myproject/static' or '/home/user/site/mymainapp/static'?

Comment: The two exist but I've try to make my nginx point to each one without success.

Comment: Ok found why : another server block on Nginx make the fool. Thanks for your help !